# What will be the Output of the following code written in “ C”?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
 char ***p="hello";
 printf("%c",++*p++);
}
```

I haven't understand why the  (*) indirection operator used here three times.

When i compiled this program then **the output was "j"**.
But actually hear the p is a pointer to pointer to pointer to Array of character.
 Then why i getting the output as j.
 I didn't understand what's the logic behind this.
Please help me to understand the actual logic behind this.

And the confusion increase more when I only use **one indirection operator** and get complied the program **.then the output is i**.means

```
void main()
{
 char *p="hello";
 printf("%c",++*p++);
}
```

Comment: Just want to let you know that `void main` isn't C: http://stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: It is undefined behavior. [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: It looks like it's relying on all of the undefined behavior ever.

Comment: @Wug, psh, it's missing a whole slew of `setjmp`/`longjmp` undefined behaviours!

Comment: @chris: thanks you chris for giving me a new knowledge but I couldn't get any stuff from that line that would have supported your statement.can you please explain me ?

Comment: @krishnaChandra, From the creator of C++: *The definition
 void main() { /* ... */ }
is not and never has been C++, nor has it even been C.* `main` should return an integer to the OS.

Comment: @chris: thank you chris ,now I got it

Comment: There's no "indirection operator used 3 times" in your code. The `*` in the declaration of `p` is not "indirection operator". It is not an operator at all. It is just a `*` - a part of the pointer declaration syntax.

Comment: @pmr: The OP's code does not suffer from undefined behavior described at your link. If the pointer values involved are valid, the `++*p++` expression is perfectly legal and has perfectly defined behavior. There are no `i = i++ + ++i`-style issues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is an undefined behavior.

Second, it isn't a correct C (or C++) code either. It generates this warning due to non-const char pointer.

```
3.c: In function 'main':
3.c:5:12: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  char ***p="hello";
            ^
```

Better do it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char ***p="hello";
    printf("%c",++*p++);

    return 0;
}
```

**And regarding what it prints:** the program has requested the run-time to terminate it in an unusual way. But this is an undefined behavior - your results may vary.

Comment: ya I compiled it,and got a warning ----suspicious pointer conversion. but after running this program i got j as an answer.

Comment: and one more think the code you suggested me is the same what i posted there despite of one think you did there i.e. int in main. and return 0 to OS

Comment: Forgot to add ``const``. Fixed it.

Comment: but still the same warning by the compilar

Comment: but didn't understand the concept behind the indirection operator used three times hare

Answer (score 2):

The code has no meaningful output as C code. The code is simply invalid.

Firstly, `void main` is not a valid declaration for `main` function in C. `main` must be declared as returning `int`.

Secondly, the `char ***p="hello"` initailization is invalid. String literal decays to has type `char *` in C. A value of type `char *` cannot be used to initialize an object of type `char ***`.

Thirdly, dereferencing a `char ***` pointer produces a pointer value of type `char **`, which cannot be `printf`-ed with `%c` format specifier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't understand why multiple indirection was used is because multiple indirection doesn't make sense here; it's just one of the many problems in this code.

`"hello"` is string literal, which is also an array expression, specifically "6-element array of `char`", which in this context is converted ("decays") to a pointer to `char`; `p` *should* be declared as

```
char *p = "hello";
```

The expression `++*p++` attempts to increment the thing `p` points to (in this case, the character `h`), and as a side effect advances `p` to point to the next character.  The behavior of modifying a string literal is *undefined*; depending on the platform, string literals may not be writable, and the expression `++*p++` may lead to an access violation.

The following is a corrected version of the above program, which gives the intended result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char h[] = "hello";
  char *p = h;
  printf("%c\n", ++*p++);
  return 0;
}
```

Instead of having `p` point to a string literal, we have it point to a local buffer that's been initialized with the *contents* of the string literal.

Comment: sir could I know the term side effect you used hare.

Comment: @krishnaChandra: "side effect" simply means that something gets modified as a result of evaluating the expression.  For example, assume `y = 0` and `x = 1`.  The expression `y=x++` has two side effects -- both `y` and `x` are modified as a result of evaluating the expression.  `y` gets the value 1 (value of `x` before the increment), and `x` gets the value 2 (new value after the increment).  The expression `++*p++` also has two side effects; both the pointer `p` and the thing it points to are being incremented by 1.

Comment: sir Could you please provide me some link that will help me understand side effect in detail.

Comment: @krishnaChandra: [Side Effect (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), from Wikipedia.  Also see the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 5.1.2.3 (Program Execution), paragraph 2.